# redirect URL with and without closing SLASH (symbol)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

I need to redirect `example.org/folder1` & `example.org/folder1/` to `example.org/file.html`

please see my code

```
Redirect 301 /folder1/   /file.html
```

this code only matches `example.org/folder1/` and ignores urls without closing `/` how can I make it work in both cases with and without `/`. Without having to repeat code twice!?

I also need it to NOT be case sensitive.

thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use RedirectMatch and make the trailing slash optional using ? char

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder1/?$ /file.html
```